# Set custom messages in Parsley.js config

Tags: parsley.js

I'm using a global configuration for parsley via: `window.ParsleyConfig = { ...my configs... }`

This works fine, but I can't figure out how to modify the default error messages. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding en default messages is quite messy atm. Please refer to this issue here https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/660 to see how you could achieve that.

Best